# In the Tsubasa Cat arc, when did Hachikuji meet Shinobu?

Tags: monogatari-series

In the Tsubasa Cat arc, I remember Hachikuji saying that she saw Shinobu at Mister Donuts and she ran away.

When did Hachikuji meet Shinobu? As far as I remember, Hachikuji never met her, except in Kabukimonogatari.

Comment: I *think* that they never actually met, but Koyomi probably mentioned Shinobu at some point, and a little blonde girl in a pilot's cap in the middle of Japan is a pretty weird thing to see, so Mayoi surmised that it was the same person. Just speculating, though.

Comment: That seems logical. What Hachikuji said to Araragi seems pretty vague. She just said that she saw Shinobu at Mister Donuts. And that she ran away. I guessed that the second sentence is because she can sense people who ran away because she is somewhat connected to that. But what alerted me is what she said first. She suddenly mentioned Shinobu so I was curious when did she met her.

Answer (score 1):

We don't see that happening but before the fight with Hanekawa, Araragi checks Mister Donut since Mayoi says she saw her in there. Because of this Araragi goes there and cant find Shinobu regardless but it is safe to assume that Shinobu hides in Araragi's shadow when he enters and the events of last arc happens.

I can also prove this with another arc in Monogatari Second Season. Spoilers!

> In Mayoi Jiangshi arc Mayoi was never able to see Shinobu thus causing the death of Araragi since she, Shinobu, wasn't able to sneak Araragi's shadow.

Since we know this fact we can say it happened on the same day.

Comment: you can hide spoilers by using `>! `

Comment: Edited accordingly.